# can the same snmp community be associated with more than one snmp version?

Tags: snmp

I guess community string is just a authentication method. So can we use the same community string say community-1 to query the device using both snmpv1 and snmpv2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use the same community string to query the device via SNMPv1 or SNMPv2C. There are no restrictions on that. Both parameters I mean version and community string are parts of SNMP packet header.